# Get hidden data using Selenium Python

Tags: html, selenium

I try to use Selenium to perform click Download button at `Historical Data/Time and Sales Historical Data` section in webpage: https://www.sgx.com/research-education/derivatives.
I use Selenium to perform download operation:

1. Click `Type of Data` and choose `Type of Data`
2. Click `Data` and choose `Data`
3. Click `Download`

Now I can download all the files and date displayed on the page. But the webpage only shows data for previous week, I want to download older files for example: files from 01 Jun 2021.

These files are not showed in webpage and html, I can't use Selenium to simulate click action. Is there any way to get the older files?

Thanks for reading and supporting!

Comment: How do you do it manually ? I see there are multiple download button  ?

Comment: I specify exact download button by using xpath.
```downloadButtonXpath = "//widget-reports-derivatives-tick-and-trade-cancellation//button[contains(@class,'sgx-button--primary')]"
```

Comment: There are five download buttons in the shared URL, and the xpath which you have shared just point to first download button, and in the drop down I can see last date as `6th-Jul-2021`, so I guess it's application that is not allowing us to select previous date

Comment: Yes, the xpath points to first download button and my target is download the files at the first download button only. So you means there is no way to get older file than ```6th-Jul-2021```?

Comment: I mean we can not do that manually as well right ?

Comment: Yes, you right.